# How do we show a Silverlight Page/Usercontrol in Tooltip

Tags: c#, silverlight

Can we show a usercontrol or a navigate to a page in Silverlight Tooltip service?
A tutorial/article link will do too. I tried to find but didn't find anything that was related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about navigating to a page, but showing a control inside a tooltip is definitely possible.

For example:

```
<Button Content="I have a tooltip which contains a control">
  <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip>
       <abc:MyUserControl />
    </ToolTip>
  </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```